# No achievement notification banners show up in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, game-center, achievements

Hoping someone can confirm or refute the fact that it appears that achievements don't show when they are achieved. When run on an iOS 6 device the achievement shows up but when run on the iOS 7 it doesn't show up.

Using `showsCompletionBanner` set to `YES`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievement_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKAchievement/showsCompletionBanner

Atm I assume it's a bug in iOS7 and it will be fixed (who knows) so I'm not touching any code.

Comment: The other day an app did show an achievement notification in-game, in one of the games I created. It seems OK now, maybe... or in other words, don't touch any code still.

Comment: Having the same issue here (working with Unity3d). Banner is not showed most of the time. But it is shown once in a century while testing.

Answer (score 3):

So with this question having no real answer for some time.

In the end, completion banners really do show in *live* apps, I guess, most of the time... eventually. While developing they don't seem to appear a lot of the times though but this should not affect the live version. I guess for various reasons a lot of these network related features don't always work 100% on sandbox servers, be it Game Center, or IAP related. This is my experience working a few years on iOS apps (above 60) anyway. I haven't done a lot of iCloud enabled apps so can't answer for that.

Of course, I haven't been doing GC achievements lately (like in the last month) so it is possible that responsiveness is better now for sandbox also.

Comment: Not seeing achievement banner even in live app

Answer (score 1):

I can only partially confirm that:

- achievements obtained in iOS 7 do show up in Game Center (on the same iOS 7 device);
- achievements obtained in iOS 6 do show up in Game Center (on the same iOS 6 device);
- however, achievements obtained on an iOS 6 device DON'T show up in Game Center on an iOS 7 device (and vice versa), even though they're logged in with the same user.
  It's like iOS 6 and iOS 7 use different repositories and are not synchronized.

Comment: OK but I was talking about completion banners that should show up instantly in-game when some achievement was... achieved.